# Parse JSON with indexes in property name to list

Tags: c#, json, .net-5

Dealing with a JSON response similar to this, some of these responses can be up to 500+ items.

```
{
    "name1": "Paul",
    "address1": "123 paul lane",
    "name2": "George",
    "address2": "123 george lane",
    "name3": "Howie",
    "address3": "123 howie lane"
}
```

I would like a way, preferably using some sort of JSON deserialization, to jam this into a list of the following object.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not opposed to writing a custom deserializer, but I am dealing with quite a few of these types of responses, and a reusable solution would be ideal here.

Comment: If at all possible I would push back on this. It looks like it was implemented by somebody that read "output JSON" on a requirement and did it without any sense. Get the response fixed to be a sane JSON output that can be serialized into a collection of `Person`. Otherwise, @Stanislas has a reasonable answer below.

Comment: @McAden I would love to push back, however this is a third party providing this data.  I do agree though.  This format is harder to consume, and I'd imagine it was harder for them to write it this way.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a very badly formatted JSON indeed.

My approach would depend on how predictable the fields are in the JSON, but if it is an endless list of key-value pairs without a pattern, I'd probably try to convert it to exactly that.

## Large JSON

Your approach will differ if the file is large or small, depending on how much memory you can afford to use for the parsing of this file.

### Using Newtonsoft.Json

See [Read JSON with JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm).

```
string json = "{\"name1\": \"Paul\",\"address1\": \"123 paul lane\",\"name2\": \"George\",\"address2\": \"123 george lane\",\"name3\": \"Howie\",\"address3\": \"123 howie lane\"}";
using var reader = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(json));
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
        case Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.PropertyName:
        case Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.String:
            Console.WriteLine($"{reader.TokenType} - {reader.Value}");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"Skipped: {reader.TokenType}");
            break;
    }
}
```

### Using System.Text.Json

See [Use Utf8JsonReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/write-custom-serializer-deserializer#use-utf8jsonreader).

```
string json = "{\"name1\": \"Paul\",\"address1\": \"123 paul lane\",\"name2\": \"George\",\"address2\": \"123 george lane\",\"name3\": \"Howie\",\"address3\": \"123 howie lane\"}";
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
var reader = new System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader(data);
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
        case System.Text.Json.JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
        case System.Text.Json.JsonTokenType.String:
            Console.WriteLine($"{reader.TokenType} - {reader.GetString()}");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"Skipped: {reader.TokenType}");
            break;
    }
}
```

### Output

Both examples above will output:

```
Skipped: StartObject
PropertyName - name1
String - Paul
PropertyName - address1
String - 123 paul lane
PropertyName - name2
String - George
PropertyName - address2
String - 123 george lane
PropertyName - name3
String - Howie
PropertyName - address3
String - 123 howie lane
Skipped: EndObject
```

## Small JSON

### Using Newtonsoft.Json

If the JSON file is small, you could parse the entire file into a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and iterate through it like that.

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetPairs()
{
    string json = "{\"name1\": \"Paul\",\"address1\": \"123 paul lane\",\"name2\": \"George\",\"address2\": \"123 george lane\",\"name3\": \"Howie\",\"address3\": \"123 howie lane\"}";
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (var pair in data)
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

An even better approach might be to use a [JTokenReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenReader.htm), but I haven't used that before.

### Using System.Text.Json

I believe the equivalent in `System.Text.Json` of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` is [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument).
See [Use JsonDocument for access to data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/write-custom-serializer-deserializer#use-jsondocument-for-access-to-data).